# PHP deja de reconocer los estilos del archivo css

Tags: php, css

La cosa es que estaba practicando hacer un crud con php y xampp pero no se porque de la nada me dejo de tomar los estilos

no se si habra algun error de sintaxis o otra cosa, agradeceria la ayuda :s

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>--</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


</head>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Con el código que has puesto, no se ve ningún error, de hecho lo he probado en un fichero html y funciona correctamente, es posible que el error lo tengas en otra parte, ¿El fichero style.css existe y está en el mismo directorio? ¿La consola del navegador te muestra algún error? ¿Podrías adjuntar el fichero generado?

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución. Mira [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).